# Class scroll when scroll direction and scroll percent is true (jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, header

I am fairly new to jQuery and JavaScript and need some help!

I am trying to make a header disappear when the user scrolls down a certain percent of the document. Also I want the header to reappear when the user scrolls up a certain percent but I just get this error in the JavaScript console: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token &

```
$(function(){

var lastScrollTop   = 0,
    delta           = 5;

$(window).scroll(function(event) {
   var scrollTop        = $(this).scrollTop(),
       scrollAmount     = $(window).scrollTop(),
       documentHeight   = $(document).height(),
       scrollPercent    = (scrollAmount / documentHeight) * 100;

   if(Math.abs(lastScrollTop - scrollTop) <= delta)
      return;

   if (scrollTop > lastScrollTop && scrollPercent > 15){
       &('.heady').slideUp(1000);

   } else if (scrollTop < lastScrollTop && scrollPercent > 30){
       &('.heady').slideDown(800);
   }
   lastScrollTop = scrollTop;
    });
});
```

If anyone could help me I would be very grateful!

Comment: Try replacing both instances of `&('.heady')` with `$('.heady')`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You try to use **&** instead of **$**.
jQuery can be used in two ways:

```
var way1 = jQuery('.classSelector');
var way2 = $('.classSelector');
```

Think about changing your code to this:

```
 if (scrollTop > lastScrollTop && scrollPercent > 15){
       $('.heady').slideUp(1000);

   } else if (scrollTop < lastScrollTop && scrollPercent > 30){
       $('.heady').slideDown(800);
   }
```

Comment: We all have been there ;) Good luck

Answer (score 0):

`.scrollTop()` may help you....

The following [Link](http://jsfiddle.net/wizam/Q34yv/1/) will show a working example.